# How to properly type a React-Native SectionList with flowjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype, flow-js

I'm trying to properly type a SectionList call on React-Native 0.66.1 with flow-bin 0.158.0

I have the following code:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, SectionList} from 'react-native';

type Props = {
  sections: $ReadOnlyArray<{
    title: string,
    data: $ReadOnlyArray<{a: string}>,
  }>,
};

const App: (props: Props) => Node = ({sections}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <SectionList sections={sections} renderItem={({item}) => null} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When I run the flowjs check I get 20 errors:

```
Cannot create SectionList element because property ItemSeparatorComponent is missing in object type [1] but exists in
SectionBase [2] in type argument SectionT. [prop-missing]


Cannot create SectionList element because property key is missing in object type [1] but exists in SectionBase [2] in
type argument SectionT. [prop-missing]

Cannot create SectionList element because property keyExtractor is missing in object type [1] but exists in
SectionBase [2] in type argument SectionT. [prop-missing]


Cannot create SectionList element because property renderItem is missing in object type [1] but exists in
SectionBase [2] in type argument SectionT. [prop-missing]
```

Here a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of error]

The error is pointing me here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1465c8f3874cdee8c325ab4a4916fda0b3e43bdb/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedSectionList.js#L43

The SectionBase definition there has key, renderItem, ItemSeparatorComponent and KeyExtractor all set to optional.

So what would be a correct type definition for my sections prop?

Comment: Not experienced with react-native here. But could you post a screenshot of the inline error? It may be helpful to see where your errors are showing, for example, what does `[1]` and `[2]` refer to?

Comment: Added to the post. @Brianzchen